# How to get states in animator?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How to get states from animator. I am trying to get the clip length of the animation through the states, the issue i am having right now is, the codes below is only work for animation clip, but If i have extra state that link to the same clip, it will not work.

```
public static AnimationClip GetAnimationClip(Animator animator, string name)
{
    //can't get data if no animator
    if (animator == null)
        return null;

    //favor for above foreach due to performance issues
    for (int i = 0; i < animator.runtimeAnimatorController.animationClips.Length; i++)
    {
        if (animator.runtimeAnimatorController.animationClips[i].name == name)
            return animator.runtimeAnimatorController.animationClips[i];
    }

    Debug.LogError("Animation clip: " + name + " not found");
    return null;
}
```

[image]

I can get the `walk` clip, but I cant get the clip of `walk_auto` which is the extra state.

Comment: Is `walk_auto` a completely separate animation, or is it duplicate state of `walk`?

Comment: @Tom it is a duplicate state of walk, which use 'walk' clip.

Comment: Then I guess this is why you can't get `walk_auto`. It is a different `state` of `walk` **not** a whole new animation clip.

Comment: yes exactly, thats why the code above only work for clip. but what i need is to get the states from animator and get the clip attached to it, so that i can get the length of the clip.